# Could one define a function as following, without leading to any contradiction?

Tags: functions

I was wondering, could one define a two variable function such that

$$T
        \begin{pmatrix}
        a \\
b\\
        \end{pmatrix}
^{T
        \begin{pmatrix}
        c \\
d\\
        \end{pmatrix}}=T        \begin{pmatrix}
        a^c \\
b^d\\
        \end{pmatrix}$$

$∀ a,b,c,d$?

---

There are only a couple of things I have been able to figure out. Assuming that one could indeed define a function as the latter, then $T        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 \\
1\\
        \end{pmatrix}=1$, since 
$T
        \begin{pmatrix}
        a \\
b\\
        \end{pmatrix}
^{T
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 \\
1\\
        \end{pmatrix}}=T        \begin{pmatrix}
        a^1 \\
b^1\\
        \end{pmatrix}$.

I also figured out that by assigning a value to a pairwise of variables in $T$, for example $$T\begin{pmatrix}
        8 \\
25\\
        \end{pmatrix}=e$$, then there are other (infinitely many) values of T that become defined, for instance $$T\begin{pmatrix}
      8^8 \\
25^{25}\\
        \end{pmatrix}=e^e$$

---

Any help/thoughts would be truly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$T(x,y) = 1$ for all $x,y$ will do the trick. Note, however, that $a^c$ and $b^d$ might not always be defined if you are allowing all real numbers.